# Dlib with CUDA and VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, dlib

I'm a long time java developer but fairly new to C++.

I have to use Dlib for my current project, i managed to run my (face detection oriented) code with it just by addig source.cpp to the project and the Dlib folder to VC++/Include.

My problem is that I have to use the dnn face detection algorithm which only yields usable speeds when running on a gpu. So I compiled Dlib with the following commands:

```
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="D:/Code/libs/cpp/cuDNN_5.0/"
cmake --build . --config Release
```

Compilation was successful without errors but then how I add it to my VS project? I tried everything for days but I cant figure it out. Any bit of help would be great.

Also, whats the difference between the different includes (VC++, C/C++, Linker) in VS? Using libs is a bit over-complicated for me compared to java.

Comment: You should just use cmake to do everything.  That's way easier than configuring VC by hand.  See: http://dlib.net/examples/CMakeLists.txt.html